# how to insert multiple lines in json array in database using php

Tags: php

I want to enter some details that included in JSON arrays to database. 
Given below is my source code.

here is my data json array from the txt file

{
   "reader_name":"Biboy Pogi",
   "mac_address":"00:16:25:10:7E:85",
   "tag_reads":[
      {
         "antennaPort":1,
         "epc":"2015031687850100010105B5",
         "tid":"E280110520005A8B952F0886",
         "isHeartBeat":false
      }
   ]
}

{
   "reader_name":"Biboy Pogi",
   "mac_address":"00:16:25:10:7E:85",
   "tag_reads":[
      {
         "antennaPort":1,
         "epc":"2015031687850100010105B5",
         "tid":"E280110520005A8B952F0886",
         "isHeartBeat":false
      }
   ]
}

Comment: __What__ is `$row`?

Comment: sorry I've changed $ row of $ data

Comment: can you echo this `$jsondata` string. not the encoded json

Comment: @Bluetree ok wait

Comment: this is the output

Comment: {"reader_name":"Biboy Pogi","mac_address":"00:16:25:10:7E:85","tag_reads":[{"antennaPort":1,"epc":"2015031687850100010105B5","tid":"E280110520005A8B952F0886","isHeartBeat":false}]} {"reader_name":"Biboy Pogi","mac_address":"00:16:25:10:7E:85","tag_reads":[{"antennaPort":1,"epc":"2015031687850100010105B5","tid":"E280110520005A8B952F0886","isHeartBeat":false}]}

Comment: [edit] your question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you source data come in one json per row. You can do the iteration insert with the below sample code:

```
$fn = 'debug.txt';
$raw = file_get_contents($fn);

$raw = explode("\r\n", $raw);
foreach($raw as $row){
    //force it to array for single item
    if (substr($row, 0, 1) != '[')
        $row = '[' . $row . ']';

    $data_arr= json_decode($row, true);

    foreach ($data_arr as $data){
        $reader_name = $data['reader_name'];
        $mac_address = $data['mac_address'];
        $antennaPort = $data['tag_reads'][0]['antennaPort'];
        $epc = $data['tag_reads'][0]['epc'];
        $tid = $data['tag_reads'][0]['tid'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO tags(reader_name, mac_address, antennaPort, epc, tid)
        VALUES('$reader_name', '$mac_address', '$antennaPort', '$epc', '$tid')";

        if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        {
            die('Error : ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your json seems to be the problem.

try this:

```
[
  {
    "reader_name": "Biboy Pogi",
    "mac_address": "00:16:25:10:7E:85",
    "tag_reads": [
      {
        "antennaPort": 1,
        "epc": "2015031687850100010105B5",
        "tid": "E280110520005A8B952F0886",
        "isHeartBeat": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "reader_name": "Biboy Pogi",
    "mac_address": "00:16:25:10:7E:85",
    "tag_reads": [
      {
        "antennaPort": 1,
        "epc": "2015031687850100010105B5",
        "tid": "E280110520005A8B952F0886",
        "isHeartBeat": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: i can not edit the json format because the device is the one that throws it

Answer (score 0):

You'r `JSON` is wrong and two times the same. Maybe you'll need it that way, but this one of them

```
{
  "reader_name": "Biboy Pogi",
  "mac_address": "00:16:25:10:7E:85",
  "tag_reads": [
      {
        "antennaPort": 1,
        "epc": "2015031687850100010105B5",
        "tid": "E280110520005A8B952F0886",
        "isHeartBeat": false
      }
  ]
}
```

And you can't reach `$antennaPort = $data['antennaPort'];` that way. You have to call it like this

```
$antennaPort = $data['tag_reads']['antennaPort'];
$epc= $data['tag_reads'][0]['epc'];
$tid= $data['tag_reads'][0]['tid'];
```

---

### EDIT

Insert into you'r database like this

```
mysqli_query($con,$sql)
```

After that, you should check for errors

```
if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
  die ('Error in query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
```

Or you go in one line

```
mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: i can not edit the json format because the device is the one that throws it

Comment: Ok.. may you just post it wrong in here. What do you mean with **so I can enter some json arrays in the database**?

Comment: is it possible to enter the database in this json format??

Comment: {  
   "reader_name":"Biboy Pogi",
   "mac_address":"00:16:25:10:7E:85",
   "tag_reads":[  
      {  
         "antennaPort":1,
         "epc":"2015031687850100010105B5",
         "tid":"E280110520005A8B952F0886",
         "isHeartBeat":false
      }
   ]
}

Comment: is it possible to enter the json array when it's lost to the closing of a json array ??

Comment: Of cause it's possible but you don't insert it. You just do `die()` if `mysqli_query` fails. You need to `mysqli_query($con, $sql) ` to insert and then ask `if (!mysqli_query) {$doSomething;}`

Comment: {  
   "reader_name":"Biboy Pogi",
   "mac_address":"00:16:25:10:7E:85",
   "tag_reads":[  
      {  
         "antennaPort":1,
         "epc":"2015031687850100010105B5",
         "tid":"E280110520005A8B952F0886",
         "isHeartBeat":false
      }
   ]
}
{  
   "reader_name":"Biboy Pogi",
   "mac_address":"00:16:25:10:7E:85",
   "tag_reads":[  
      {  
         "antennaPort":1,
         "epc":"2015031687850100010105B5",
         "tid":"E280110520005A8B952F0886",
         "isHeartBeat":false
      }
   ]
}
its is possible insert to MySQL database?? this format??

Comment: im wrong in question it is possible insert into database the multiple json array? example:
{
} this is 1 json array right
after 2 minutes or 15 second the device is throw new json 
{
this is my 1 json
}
{
2 json
}
possible to insert to database multiple array??
@MaximilianFixl

Comment: You can insert into `TEXT` column or from mysql 5.7 on (I guess the version), you can have as `JSON` column in mysql.

Comment: can i please example code i do not know how to php @MaximilianFixl

Comment: Do you create your table with phpmyadmin?

Comment: Go to your table -> **structure** -> click **edit** -> see the target column line -> change the drop down **type** to `JSON` or `TEXT` -> *ok*

Comment: @MaximilianFixl sir??

Comment: Yes, did you‘ve been successful?

Comment: no sir because the code is inserting every new json array but not insert the json array format like this [{json1},{json2},{json3}]

Comment: Dind'nt know, that your `json` comes from a `.txt`. Ok let me try to understand you'r complete case. ***1***. You've got a `.txt` with `json` strings in. ***2*** You need to get each object and have to insert it in a mysql database?